# Why ChatGPT in Website version gives better answer than the PlayGround or the app?

Tags: chatgpt, openai

I have tried to ask ChatGPT (3.5), and did the same question in the app version and in Playground, and the best answer was the one given by the website.
I am just curios to know why?

Comment: Which model did you use in playground? Also, was it Azure playground?

Comment: I used this [link](https://platform.openai.com/playground?model=gpt-3.5-turbo-16k)

Comment: Could you share an example of what you asked? It's hard to know whether it gave you the best subjective or factual answer. If it's something subjective, it might just be the answer you like the most and have little to do with the medium of which you asked it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be due to different reasons:

- You are not using the same model under the hood. You can see what model you are using on the Chat, as well as the PlayGround. You may be using different models.
- The parameters used by this models. In the playground you can tune them
- The prompt. The instructions given to ChatGPT are key for the results you get. The application and the chat may use a predefined prompt. In the playground, you can define it beforehand. But in any case you can also instruct ChatGPT about how to behave or give the answer. For example:

> Your task is to reply my answer in a clear and concise way. Use simple words, give an example and references. The answer must not be longer than one paragraph or 100 words. My question is...

Answer (score 3):

ChatGPT's answers have some stochastic component. So even the same model can answer differently to the same prompt.

For some questions and answers this stochastic variation in answers can make the difference between a correct and a false answer. Therefore one anecdotal Q&A session is not enough to decide on which model is better, or performing better. You would have to repeat the experiment some more times, even just for a particular question. And then the result of that experiment would not generalize well to other questions. Comparing the statistical performance or "intelligence" of LLM's is not a trivial task. If you just want to find out which LLM you want to use for a particular type of task, test it with more data and questions, and keep testing once every while because the models are changed regularly. And unfortunately, they do not always improve in all performance aspects.